# How to make section hero (with image slider) always fit browser height?

Tags: html, css, image, slider, height

I'm currently working on a website but I'm having some issues.
On the homepage, I have a responsive slider and I'd like it to always fit the browser height, on any size of screen/window.
I've managed to make it (almost) always fit the browser height but, as it's a responsive slider, when I resize my browser window, at some point, the height diminishes to keep the ratio of the pictures.

What I'd like is that the height of the slider/pictures remains 100% of the browser window, on any size of screen (desktop/mobile), and that the pictures of the slider keep their ratio (by cutting / zooming the images in their width, but not by crushing them).

Here's the link of the homepage: http://iampox.com/juno/
And here's my HTML and css:

```css
/* =Home slider
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.rslides {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100vh;
}

.rslides li {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.rslides img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rslides">
 <li><img src="img/slide1@1x.jpg" alt="Slide 1"></li>
 <li><img src="img/slide2@1x.jpg" alt="Slide 2"></li>
 <li><img src="img/slide3@1x.jpg" alt="Slide 3"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you want to support, you can use vh:

```
.rslides img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

Or you could try [Superslides](http://nicinabox.com/superslides)

Comment: I've already tried that but it's not working. In fact, I'd like to have [something like that](http://iampox.com) (the video that fits the height of the browser window whatever is the width) but with my slider.
I'm currently using [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com)